# What happens when you have two Google Cloud projects with overlapping DNS zones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

A question about Google Cloud DNS: what happens when you create two Google Cloud projects (e.g., ProjectA and ProjectB), each with a public managed DNS zone with the same top-level domain (e.g., example.com)?

More precisely: will the sub-domains of both (e.g., a.example.com in ProjectA and b.example.com in ProjectB) both be resolvable by clients?

And more exotically: what would happen if both projects would define the same subdomain (e.g., an A record for overlapping.example.com)?

I've read Google's [documentation on overlapping zones](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#overlapping), but that does not seem to give an answer to these questions.

Any experiences?

Answer (score 18):

If you have a public domain managed in one Project and you want to setup subdomain in a different Project then you can follow this:

Let's have *Project A* that contains *Zone X* for `domain.com` that is registered with Google's NS servers `ns-cloud-a{1..4}.googledomains.com`.

Then let's have *Project B* that contains *Zone Y* for `dev.domain.com` that is registered with Google's NS servers `ns-cloud-b{1..4}.googledomains.com`.

In order to make domain names from *Zone Y* public, create `NS` record for `dev.domain.com` that points to `ns-cloud-b{1..4}.googledomains.com` in the *Zone X*.

Comment: This is very useful, specially if you want to use different service accounts to manage DNS and want the subdomain SA isolated from changing main DNS.

Comment: Thank you it work for me but Be patient it can take some time, in my case it take more or less 3 hours.

Answer (score -1):

TLDR

A parent domain project needs an NS record for the subdomain, configured with subdomain name server.